# What's the simplest method for comparing tables and generating matches? Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, query-builder

I've got two tables, one to hold the user's data and the other to hold the agency data. 
I'm trying to figure out how to compare certain user details with agency details. For instance matching spoken languages with languages wanted.

There seems to be a number of ways to do this, right now I'm just trying to figure out how to do it however.

Thanks to a quirk of rebuilding an old system, the old data is stored like so: 
French,Russian,Mandarin,Thai,Indonesian,Arabic,Indian,Asian

Which means I grab the data from a table and have to explode it first

```
$agency = AgencyLogin::find(196);
$language = $agency->Languages;
$lang = explode(',', $language);
```

I get a bit confused after that however, as then I need to take this agency language profile, and compare it with all the users and print the users that have a language match and what those matches are.

Right now I'm trying something very crude that does not work for a different info set:

```
$ministry = AgencyLogin::find(184);
        $prefs = $ministry->Ministry_Preferences;
        $tags = explode(',', $prefs);
        $sub_categories = DB::table('descriptor')
            ->whereIn('tag', $tags)
            ->get(['subcategory', 'description']);

        $match = DB::table('users')->select('Ministry_Preferences');

        $matches = [];
        foreach ($match as $mat) {
            $user = explode(',', $mat);
            $inter = $tags->intersect($user);
            $matches = array_add($matches, $inter);
        }
        $view->with(['sub_categories', $sub_categories], ['matches', $matches]);
```

Obviously, some of you will look at this and go, 'Don't store data like that you moron' and I would agree with you, but there is a lot of data stored this way, and that means I have to rebuild large portions of the database, link everything correctly, and then write migration code to properly migrate the current live one into the format of the current local dev database when we eventually go live. That would take a while, as I'd have to learn how to do each step and likely break things in the process so... Let's keep the duct tape for now.

Comment: Show the code you have tried already.

Comment: I added what I'm currently trying. But it doesn't work at the moment because I'm not using intersect properly. - never used it before.

Answer (score 1):

**First approach**

If you store languages for users the same way as for agencies, my advice is to add `,` in the beginning and at the end of the languages (in users table) string like this: `,French,Russian,Mandarin,Thai,Indonesian,Arabic,Indian,Asian,` so you will be able to build an easy `SELECT` query to search in this column.

Example query to update all the records:

```
UPDATE table SET languages=CONCAT(',',languages,',') WHERE 1
```

Then as you wrote in your question, get the agency languages, split them and iterate over them. And in this loop query users table to find users that match current language in this way:

```
SELECT ... FROM users WHERE language LIKE ('%,:language,%)
```

or

```
$agencyLanguage = ','.$agencyLanguage.',';
SELECT ... FROM users WHERE language LIKE ('%$agencyLanguage%)
```

where :language is the binded language (one of the many in the loop) of the agency.

**Another approach**

If your current DB engine supports Full text search then you can put FULL TEXT INDEX on the column that you will search against (as I understand that will be `languages` column in `users` table). Then you will get agency languages, this time **NOT** exploded by `,` but replaced like that:

```
   $agencyLanguages = '+"French" +"Russian" +"Mandarin"';
```

and then you can use this in the searching query:

```
  SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH (quote) AGAINST (:agencyLanguages IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: This is quite far ahead of my current knowledge of databasing. But I assume this would require a few DBraw queries in laravel?

Comment: Yes, if you talking about the second approach. But it is more optimal way (if the column doesn't contain too many languages separated with `,`)

Comment: Well, I got no clue how to implement the first in laravel, but I'll see if I can learn how to do full text search with php then learn how to do that with laravel I suppose. According to the docs it's not officially supported.

Comment: The first approach should not be that hard to implement in laravel. I added the update query for all the records in the answer. You just have to implement this type of query `WHERE language LIKE ('%,:language,%)` in your code (it should be supported in laravel I think).